# How to get the text only from the child element - Webdriver - Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver, element

I am trying to get the text only from a child element. See below:

```
<strong class="EnvMain">
  <strong id="currentClock">11:19</strong>
  GMT
</strong>
```

I would like to get only the GMT text.

I tried writing the xpath like: `.//*[@id='userEnvironmentInfo']/div[2]/a/strong/text()]` but this way the element is not found.

Thanks in advance.

Update of HTML:

```
<div class="DateTime">
 <a class="EnvPicker" title="Change your timezone" href="javascript:void(0);">
  <span class="EnvDD">▾</span>
  <span class="EnvIcon DateTimeIcon">The time is:</span>
  <strong class="EnvMain">
    <strong id="currentClock">17:34</strong>
    GMT
    </strong>
  <span id="currentDay" class="EnvMore">Monday</span>
  <span id="currentDate" class="EnvMore">14.04.2014</span>
 </a>
 <div class="EnvContainer">
   <ol id="timeZoneOptions" class="EnvList">
      <li class="EnvItem">
         <a class="EnvOption" title="Set the timezone to GMT-12" onclick="return false;" rel="-12" href="javascript:void(0);">
             <strong class="EnvMain">GMT-12</strong>
             <span class="EnvMore">Current time:01:25</span>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="EnvItem">
         <a class="EnvOption" title="Set the timezone to GMT-11" onclick="return false;" rel="-11" href="javascript:void(0);">
```

and here the elements will continue until GMT +12.

Comment: You've got a typo - there's an extra trailing `]` after `text()` that shouldn't be there.  Does it work if you remove that?

Comment: This isn't going to work. `text()` isn't going to return a DOM element that Selenium can use.

Comment: Yea, sorry for the typo, already removed that, it returns 11:19
GMT.

Answer (score 0):

The xpath you're searching for is:

```
//strong[@class='EnvMain']/text()
```

This xpath returns text, not a web element.

If you want to get text using selenium + java you can try the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//strong[@class='EnvMain']")).getText();
```

Seems like getText Function will not return only `GMT`. But we can parse a string like this after getting the text:

```
    String s = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//strong[@class='EnvMain']/strong[id='currentClock']/..")).getText();
    s = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did as you said but as it seems there is another drop-down list that has the same class(EnvMain) and the text will be taken only from that element.

Comment: Try this for strong `//strong[@class='EnvMain'][2]` or provide more html, can't help without seeing it.

Comment: Thanks, again element is not found. More HTML added in post.

Comment: Try to use xpath from @TJanesBoone answer and add `/text()` to it. Seems like getText function will not help here. But you can use it and parse string then.

Comment: The element is not found when I run the test, but if I write the xpath in View Xpath in Firefox, the correct text is shown(GMT).

Comment: Element is not found because `text()` is not a WebElement. I've updated my answer with workaround. Please try it.

Comment: same result, and also element is not found, i wrote it like   //strong[@class='EnvMain']/strong[@id='currentClock'] in order to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the following xpath to find the element:

```
//strong[@class='EnvMain']/strong[@id='currentClock']/..
```

What this xpath does is it finds the `<strong>` element with class EnvMain that has a child `<strong>` with an id of currentClock.  (The `..` at the end walks back up the dom to the parent element).

Then extract the text with the `getText()` method:

```java
   String gmt = driver
        .getElement(By.xpath("//strong[@class='EnvMain']/strong[id='currentClock']/.."))
        .getText();
```

Then, if you want to ignore the text in the inner `<strong>` element and only get the timezone ("GMT")... there's not a good way to do this with xpath.  You'll have to use a regular expression in Java to remove the part you don't want:

```
gmt = gmt.replaceAll("[\\d][\\d]?:[\\d][\\d]\\s*", "");
```

Comment: Thanks, again the text returned will be the clock and time zone.

Comment: Wait, I'm a bit confused... do you want to get only "GMT" or "hh:mm GMT"?

Comment: Yes, as I said in the post "I would like to get only the GMT text."

Answer (score 0):

getText() returns null in your case, because in list item there is anchor tag and then text for anchor tag.So use getAttribute("innerHTML"). But  you will not be able to select the item in list.

```
WebElement e1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='EnvContainer']"));

List<WebElement> list = e1.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
for(WebElement item: list)
 {
    String s = item.getAttribute("innerHTML");
    System.out.println(item.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
    }
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class=EnvContainer')).click();                  

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='EnvList']//*[text()='GMT']")).click();